# Missing module directory etc. when building kernel for raspberry pi 4b

Tags: apt, kernel, compiling

I am trying to build the kernel from source on a raspberry pi 4b  uname -a shows

```
Linux ubuntu-pi-kit 5.13.0-1025-raspi #27-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 5 12:08:41 UTC 2022 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I downloaded the kernel source with

```
fakeroot apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

The kernel gets built, but when I try to install it there seems to be a version error with for example the kernel modules

```
/kernel/linux-raspi-5.13.0$ sudo make install
```

followed by errors

```
sh ./arch/arm/boot/install.sh "5.13.19" \
arch/arm/boot/Image System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 5.13.19 /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.19
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 5.13.19 /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.19
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.19
W: missing /lib/modules/5.13.19
W: Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/5.13.19: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
cat: /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_hWlPd7/lib/modules/5.13.19/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
W: Can't find modules.builtin.modinfo (for locating built-in drivers' firmware, supported in Linux >=5.2)
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.order at /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_hWlPd7/lib/modules/5.13.19: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.builtin at /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_hWlPd7/lib/modules/5.13.19: No such file or directory
Using DTB: bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
Couldn't find DTB bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb on the following paths: /etc/flash-kernel/dtbs /usr/lib/linux-image-5.13.19 /lib/firmware/5.13.19/device-tree/
Installing  into /boot/dtbs/5.13.19/./bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
cp: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//flash-kernel exited with return code 1
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/boot/Makefile:107: install] Error 1
```

When I compiled the kernel it did spend a lot of time compiling kernel modules.

OK I found that I need to add make_install as in

```
sudo make modules_install  install
```

to get the modules singed and placed in the proper spot. However the dtb file is still missing.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The [RaspberryPi kernel doc](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html) shows `make -j4 Image.gz modules dtbs`. Make sure that you include the `dtbs`.